# Is function template specialization really allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

As per [this article](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/partial-template-specialization/), which says that( *emphasis mine* ):

> Partial template specialization allows us to specialize classes (but
> not **individual functions**!)

It seems that function partial template specialization is not allowed.  Is that really correct?

What confuses me is that why these code snippets could be compiled successfully:

```
//demo1.cpp
//first code snippet(https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0868610b5be94f2c)
//Why this function template specialization compiles? 
//Because this is full template specialization other than partial template specialization?Am I right?
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void f(T)
{ 
    T d; 
    std::cout <<"first one" << std::endl;
}
    
template <>
void f<int>(int)
{ 
    int d;
    std::cout <<"second one" << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    f(5.0);
    f(1);
    f('a');
}
```

Another example:

```
//demo2.cpp(https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7b1a94ad377ac1f6)
//Why this function template specialization compiles? 
//I think it's function partial template specialization indeed.
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

//function template
template<typename T, class N> void compare(T num1, N num2) {
    cout << "standard function template" << endl;
    if(num1>num2)
        cout << "num1:" << num1 << " > num2:" << num2 <<endl;
    else
        cout << "num1:" << num1 << " <= num2:" << num2 << endl;
}

//function partial template specialization
template<class N> void compare(int num1, N num2) {
    cout<< "partitial specialization" <<endl;
    if (num1>num2)
        cout << "num1:" << num1 << " > num2:" << num2 << endl;
    else
        cout << "num1:" << num1 << " <= num2:" << num2 << endl;
}

int main() {
    compare<int,int>(30,31);//call compare<int,int>(int num1, int num2)
    
    compare(5,9);           //call compare<int>(int num1, int num2)

    compare(30,'1');        //call compare<char>(int num1, char num2)

}
```

Why [this code snippet](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd3ad66acc4cb871) could not been compiled whereas the aforementioned two code snippets compile successfully?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

template <class T1, class T2>
void f(){}
    
template <class T2>
void f<int, T2>(){}  //It's function template sepcialization, isn't it? Why it could not be compiled?

int main() {}
```

Here are the error messages:

> ```
> main.cpp:9:6: error: non-type partial specialization 'f<int, T2>' is not allowed
>     9 | void f<int, T2>(){}
>       |      ^~~~~~~~~~
> ```

**EDITED**:
Thanks to eerorika for the detailed explaination.

One more question raises, **how** to **distinguish** the overloading templates and partially specialising function templates?

In other words, **why**  `template<class N> void compare(int num1, N num2)` is a template overload **whereas**    `template <class T2>    void f<int, T2>(){}` is attempting to partially specialise a function template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is function template specialization really allowed?

Yes, but not partial specialisation.

> It seems that function partcial template specialization is not allowed.Is it really correct?

If you mean **partial** specialisation, that is indeed not allowed for function templates.

> ```
> // Why this fucntion template specialization compiles? 
> // Because this is full template specialization ...?Am I right?
> ```

Yes.

> ```
> //Why this fucntion template specialization compiles? 
> //I think it's function partcial template specialization
> ```

No, that is not a template specialisation at all. That is a separate template. It is an overload.

> Why this code snippet could not been compiled

Because it attempts to partially specialise a function template.

---

> how to distinguish the overloading templates and partially specialising function templates?

The syntax of function specialisation is:

```
template<>
ReturnType template_name<template_argument_list>(parameter_list) {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If the syntax isn't this, then it isn't a function specialisation. Notice the highlighted part that is missing from your example that isn't a specialisation. If that part is left out, this becomes a primary template definition.

Comment: One more question raises, how to distinguish the overloading templates and partially specialising function templates?

Thank you for the detailed explaination.In other words, why  template<class N> void compare(int num1, N num2) is a template overload whereas    template <class T2>    void f<int, T2>(){} is attempting to partially specialise a function template?

Comment: Thank you so much. My understanding of this question is at a different level with your generous help.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my last question.

Its *syntax* should have looked somewhat like the below one, if it attempts to specialise a function template.

```
//attempt to specialise a function template
template<class N> void compare<int, N>(int num1, N num2) {
    cout<< "partitial specialization" <<endl;
    if (num1>num2)
        cout << "num1:" << num1 << " > num2:" << num2 << endl;
    else
        cout << "num1:" << num1 << " <= num2:" << num2 << endl;
}
```